# SSLHandshakeException using Apache HttpClient and IBM Jsse2 on WAS 9

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, sslhandshakeexception, sslcontext

I have a webapp where I use HttpClient to send get/Post requests to some webpages and validate the response. The application was working fine for a long time when it was deployed on Tomcat 8.5 but now due to company guidelines, I need to use Websphere. So when I deployed this application on WAS 9, my http requests started to fail with SSL exceptions.

While debugging this issue, I noticed that the place where I build http client, Tomcat version of my webapp provides Sun Jsse implementation of JSSEProvider but The app which is deployed on WAS, gets IBM Jsse2 provider. I was wondering if this would be the reason for SSL exceptions and is there any way I can switch to Sun Jsse? Here is the place where SSlContext is set -

```
HttpClient client = null;
        try {

            HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());

            // setup a Trust Strategy that allows all certificates.
//Here I get sslContext as IBM Jsse2 vs Sun Jsse
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();

            builder.setSSLContext(sslContext);

            // don't check Hostnames, either.
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
```

Here is the console log -

```
[8/30/19 5:51:06:758 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
[8/30/19 5:51:06:759 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:782)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:760 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.av.i(av.java:574)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:760 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:280)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:761 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.av.startHandshake(av.java:431)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:762 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:762 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:762 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:763 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:763 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:765 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:765 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:766 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:766 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:766 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:767 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:767 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:767 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:768 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at validation.BrowserValidation.getPage(BrowserValidation.java:370)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:768 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at validation.BrowserValidation.startValidation(BrowserValidation.java:83)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:768 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at validation.ValidationMaster.routeValidation(ValidationMaster.java:119)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:769 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at validation.ServerValidation.onMessage(ServerValidation.java:60)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:769 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:769 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:770 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:770 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:771 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wsoc.LinkRead.callOnMessage(LinkRead.java:1150)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:771 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wsoc.LinkRead.processOnMessageTextAnnotation(LinkRead.java:1003)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:772 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wsoc.LinkRead.processRead(LinkRead.java:319)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:772 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wsoc.WsocConnLink.processRead(WsocConnLink.java:978)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:773 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wsoc.WsocReadCallback.complete(WsocReadCallback.java:29)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:773 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:774 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:774 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:774 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:775 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:776 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:776 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:777 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:778 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
[8/30/19 5:51:06:779 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:231)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:780 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:579)
[8/30/19 5:51:06:780 CDT] 000000a5 SystemErr     R  ... 37 more
```

Can it be any other issue?

Update:
I checked the server logs and here is what it says -

```
[9/3/19 5:04:45:670 CDT] 0000019a SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D.z(D.java:531)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.b(aq.java:271)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.c(aq.java:236)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.wrap(aq.java:599)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:21)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:811)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:617)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:346)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
        at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:24)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:604)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:564)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:522)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.F.a(F.java:673)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.F.a(F.java:782)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D.r(D.java:176)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D$b.a(D$b.java:3)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D$b.run(D$b.java:4)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:730)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.D$c.run(D$c.java:2)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:898)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: have you debugged the remote side? The exception says the other side abruptly closed the connection.

Comment: The other side is valid production server and same app which is deployed on Tomcat gets proper response without any issue.

Comment: So "no".  Seems like a good next step.

Comment: I can certainly look at that but I was wondering if the same application on Tomcat is able to get correct response from remote site, shouldn't I look at what's wrong with the version of my app which is deployed on websphere?

Comment: yes, and the errors from the server will inform that investigation.

Comment: I have updated the question with the server log.

Comment: I read somewhere that I can update default ssl settings in Security -- SSL Certificate and Key Management -- SSL Configurations -- Protocol = 1.2
I did that and still getting the error. And now I cannot even change above setting as I don't see any default configuration for my node there.

Comment: @covener Would you be able to help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the  HttpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties().build() method instead to create an instance of HTTPClient.
IBM implements its own SSLSocketFacxtory which eventually get invoked on WAS with IBM JDK.
More details on [IBM site](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/im-using-apache-httpclient-make-outbound-call-my-web-application-running-websphere-application-server-traditional-and-im-getting-ssl-handshake-error-how-can-i-debug)